# How to verify if a given number is a decimal expansion of $\pi$?

Tags: algorithms, pi

Let's say I am given a number $x$ and I want to check if $x$ is a valid truncation of $\pi$, so for example 3, 3.14 or 3.1415. Is there an algorithm for this that's faster than computing the value of $\pi$ to the required accuracy (using an existing algorithm), and then comparing the digits?

For example, if somebody claimed that $x$ is approximately the golden ratio, I could always check if $x + 1 \approx x^2$ to see if they're right. Is there a similar check for $\pi$?

If checking for a **trunctation** is too difficult, the more laxed version would check for a good-enough **approximation**, so accurate to some $\pm 10^{-k}$ or something.

Comment: Interesting question.  One could, for instance, compute $\sin(\alpha)$ and check to see if it was as close to $0$ as it ought to be.  But, $\sin$ is a transcendental function and working with the Taylor expansion is unlikely to impress you with its efficiency.

Comment: If you want to permit $3.1415$ and not $3.1416$ (because the latter, while a better approximation, is not a strict truncation), then you're dependent on the decimal representation of $\pi$ and my intuition is that there is no faster algorithm than brute force.  (That's not to say that there is a faster algorithm if you just need approximations.)

Comment: Oh, @BrianTung  makes a good point.  My method, working with $\sin(\alpha)$ or the like, only tells you if you have a good *approximation* to $\pi$, not a truncation.

Comment: @lulu: Could check that $\sin \frac{\alpha}{6} \approx \frac12$, which at least gets faster convergence.

Comment: Good point, let me add it as a less strict condition.

Comment: @BrianTung  Sure, but since you need to treat the error analysis sensitively, I kind of doubt this is an improvement over just comparing the digits.  For approximation to, say, $\sqrt 2$, I expect it is better to square.

Comment: @lulu: Oh, I agree.  I don't think there *is* a better algorithm than just computing the digits.  There are some awfully fast $\pi$ computation algorithms.

Comment: Compare the continued fraction expansions of $\pi$ and your $\hat\pi$. At least it's independent of the basis. See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Continued_fraction#Continued_fraction_expansion_of_π_and_its_convergents

Comment: If you convert the approximation to hex digits, there is a formula, called the Bailey–Borwein–Plouffe formula, that calculates the n-th hex digit without calculating all the previous digits. This can be used to verify a calculation of digits of $\pi$.   https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bailey%E2%80%93Borwein%E2%80%93Plouffe_formula

Answer (score 0):

Ramanujan has this formula which gives you 8 more decimal digits with each extra term.

6$$\frac{1}{\pi} = \frac{2\sqrt{2}}{9801} \sum^\infty_{k=0} \frac{(4k)!(1103+26390k)}{(k!)^4 396^{4k}}$$

Comment: The Chudnovsky brothers developed a similar formula, $\frac{1}{\pi}
= \frac{1}{53360 \sqrt{640320}}
\sum_{n=0}^\infty (-1)^n
\frac{(6n)!}{n!^3(3n)!} \times
\frac{13591409 + 545140134n}{640320^{3n}}$ that produces 14 decimal digits for each term, but the catch is verifying whether an implementation of this formula is correct . The Bailey–Borwein–Plouffe formula provides a means of verification. See, for example, https://pi-calculator.netlify.app/